# Populate Access Listbox based on another listbox input

Tags: ms-access, listbox

I'm developing an Access form (first time ever doing this). There are currently 2 listboxes on the form. I need the second listbox to populate a list of employees based on the which manager is selected in the first listbox. I have separate tables created for each manager that contains their individual list of employees. When the manager chooses their name in the first listbox (which I've already populated), I need to second listbox to populate with the list that is for that manager. Hope that made sense. I've searched all over the place and can't seem to find a solid answer to this.

Comment: [This applies to listboxes and comboboxes](http://www.fmsinc.com/microsoftaccess/forms/combo-boxes/cascading.html)

Comment: It sounds as if your data structure is wrong if you have a table for each manager. You should either store the managers ID in the employee's records, or if you want to record when managers changed have a separate table listing the manager ID's and employee ID's with a start and end date.